# VPN Proxy Server

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy

I need some help describing the issue I have so I might be using wrong concepts.

What I want to create is a secure and anonymous connection between my computer (A Windows 10 Virtual PC) and a remote server. The trafic will be FTP(s) and http(s).

So far I understand that I need a VPN for the security and a Proxy for the  anonymity. The remote server supports Open VPN (I have limited/no control of the server to install stuff). I have full control over my own Windows 10 PC. Also I have the possibility to install a small computer (like a Raspberry Pi) as a proxy on an intermediate location. The intermediate location is behind a NAT.

First of all I need some feedback if this is at all the best way to go. Secondly I need som possible solutions how to do this.

Comment: WHat's the intermediate proxy supposed to be good for?

Comment: I am not sure I understand why you need a proxy. Since the remote server uses OpenVPN, the communication is encrypted, so no one will be able to know where you will be going to, after having touched base on your remote server. What is the proxy there to do? By using a proxy you will only be hiding where your remote server is. Is that so important?

Comment: If you get access to the remote server would'nt you be able to see the IP address of my Windows 10 PC ? - even though the line is encrypted?

Comment: WHo is "you" in your question?

Comment: If an intruder gets access to the remote server, all of your communications are in the clear, you are done. How would a proxy along the way improve your situation?  If I have the resources to intercept traffic from all pcs (a government agency!) I can follow your communication from home to the proxy, then from the proxy to the server. It is only a tad more boring than without a proxy. If you want to protect yourself from government agenies, then you need to use `Tor, the onion router`. OpenVPN is not much help againsta government agencies.

Comment: MariusM but would the Proxy help you there. You would have to get info about the traffic - Let's say the proxy is located in a place where the remote server intruder does not have control. I am thinking in that situation the proxy would hide me.